# Runbook Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd SQL Server MI connection

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a some Powershell code to drop a database on a SQL Server Managed Instance that I would like to schedule via Azure Automation.  The code runs fine in the Windows Powershell ISE.

```
#Type the Managed instance admin login
$username =  "uname"
#Type the Managed instance admin password
$password =  'pwd'
#Type the Full Managed instance name
$managedInstance =  "sql-srvr_mangedinstance.database.windows.net"
#Leave this parameter as is
$database =  "master"
#Drop Database before restore
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $managedInstance -Database $database -Username $username -Password $password -Query "DROP DATABASE [DB_NAME]"
Write "Dropped Database DB_NAME"
```

Unfortunately it gives me this error when I run it via the Runbooks on Azure.

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
>   The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is 
>   configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the 
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected 
>   host has failed to respond.)
>   At line:32 char:1
>   + Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $managedInstance -Database $database -U ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExceptionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
>   Invoke-Sqlcmd : 
>   At line:32 char:1
>   + Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $managedInstance -Database $database -U ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

I have seen resolutions to this by changing the Server connection to "Server=tcp:managedinstancename.database.windows.net:1433" but this seems to be more towards a Sql Server DB on a vm.  I have also included the Import-Module Sqlserver command at the top of my code even though this module is already in the runbooks module blade.  Using SSMS to connect to the Instance I can confirm the Allow Remote connections box is ticked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the latest Azure Rm SQL commandlets and remove the database.

```
   # Get the current context of the account which can perform operations on the database server
    $Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
    Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId $conn.SubscriptionId -ErrorAction Stop | Write-Verbose

    # assign resourcegroup, database server and database names
    $rgname = "rgname"
    $dbservername = "servername"
    $dbname = "dbname"

    if(Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $rgname -ServerName $dbservername -DatabaseName $dbname)
        {
        Try{
            Remove-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $rgname -ServerName $dbservername -DatabaseName $dbname -Force
            Write-Output "Dropped Database $database"
        }Catch{
            $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Output $errorMessage
            Write-Output 'Failed to delete database'
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.